# Check if MySQL database is updated using MD5 hash

Tags: php, android, mysql

i'm creating a android app that connects with a MySQL server. Now to reduce the data transference I want to give the database/table a (md5?)hash value(if possible) and send that hash to my app and compare it with the hash value of the data on the app. So theoretically if the hashes are different, the database on the server has been updated and then the app should download the data from the server. If the hashes are the same it shouldn't download the update.

Now... is this possible? and if it is how should i achieve this? 
I've looked around and people saying that you should use a timestamp to see if it has been updated. 
I prefer a hash, i don't think it is better but it's just a preference.

How can I achieve to create a MD5 of the table, send it to the app, and compare it to the MD5 of the existing table.

Tnx

Comment: Cant you have a version id and compare version ids instead?

Comment: Can i retreive a version id of a table by default? Or should i create a method for that? Because else it's just the same as retrieving a MD5

Comment: I meant why not have a separate column with VersionId, that is updated whenever there is a change to the underlying data, which can then be compared with the server's id to see if syncing is necessary. Calculating hash on an entire table/database is a costly affair.

Comment: Yes but then i have to compare every single item in the table for the version id. I want to compare the whole table at once. But i think i already found a solution.. I'm gonna work it out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting whole table to md5 u can keep an column in table which will change dynamically on data update,then only send that column value to app and compare.You can use cron job to auto check updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use php md5:

```
$password = md5($password);
$query = "UPDATE user SET password='".$password."' WHERE username='".$username."'";
```